# Enfermer, renfermer, enclore et inclure

Tags: vocabulaire, choix-de-mot, mathématiques

J’ai lu une poignée de mots qui ont l’air de vouloir dire peu ou prou la même chose, à savoir :

> Enfermer, renfermer, enclore, inclure.

Je montre ce que je pense du sens de ces mots. J’espère que vous pourrez me mettre au courant des sous-entendus que j’ai ratés. C’est également mon dessein d’apprendre comment les mots s’emploient en mathématiques ensemblistes.

On dit qu’une chose enferme un truc lorsque le truc se trouve dedans. Cela paraît net et sans ambiguïté.

S’il ne s’agit pas d’enfermer de nouveau, *renfermer* me semble un mot plus fort, qui convient mieux lorsqu’on s'efforce de détenir quelque chose où quelqu’un. Je dirais que ce mot peut également approcher resserrer, rétrécir un espace fermé dans lequel se situe un autre truc.

On enclot quelque chose si on fait une bâtisse qui enferme quelque chose, n’est-ce pas ? Peut-on dire qu’une courbe enclot un morceau du plan réel ?

Dernièrement, le mot « inclure » s’emploie plus souvent pour des liaisons entre deux objets impalpables. Un prix par exemple, peut inclure ou exclure des taxes. Je crois que ce mot est usité en mathématiques.

Comment: Tu pourrais éventuellement ajouter à la liste *circonscrire*, *contenir*, voire *englober*, qui ont également des cas d'usage en mathématiques.

Comment: Je crois qu'on dit qu'une courbe *délimite* une partie d'un plan.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Enfermer* implique une limitation de la liberté: ce qui est dedans est censé y rester et on fait tout ce qui est possible pour qu'il le reste.

*Renfermer* signifie "contenir", du moins au sens figuré ("Ce livre renferme un secret."). *Re-* a ici en effet un sens différent de son usage le plus commun, et se rapproche plutôt de celui qu'on voit dans des mots comme *revenir*, *redescendre* et *repartir*.

Pour moi, *enclore* ne s'emploie qu'au sens physique pour une barrière qui ne s'accompagne pas d'un toit: clôture, mur de jardin, haie... Mais dans l'ensemble, c'est un terme un peu daté.

Pour le reste, tes intuitions me semblent correctes, mais je suis d'accord avec user2572030 concernant *délimiter*.